# Use of "modulo" operation in place of integer division

Tags: algorithms

would someone please help me with this problem. So earlier, I asked this question: [Row and column algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314978/row-and-column-algorithm)

And got an answer: The row is :$$r = \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{t} \right\rfloor + 1$$

This involves dividing by int. variables like in computer programming. However, I am wondering if there is a formula that does not involve dividing by int. variables and just uses modulo.

My attempt:

n - ((n-1)%t) + 1

Doesn't seem to work. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: I've attempted to make the title more informative, while staying true to the intent of the problem. Feel free to re-title if I've missed the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}t\right\rfloor$ is not `(n-1)%t`. It is `int((n-1)/t)`.

If you really want to "just use modulo" you can apply the identity that says that $$\left\lfloor\frac ab\right\rfloor = \frac{a-a\bmod b}b,$$ which says that you can use `(n-1-(n-1)%t) / t`.  But that seems a little bit silly.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know the actual modulo identity. Hopefully I will learn a lot more when I start taking computer science courses.

Is there a reference page where I can learn more about modulos? How is that formula derived and how does modulo actually work (the formula)?

Comment: The real identity is that $a  = b\cdot\left\lfloor\frac ab\right\rfloor + a\bmod b$.  When you divide $a$ by $b$, there is a quotient, which is $\left\lfloor\frac ab\right\rfloor$, and a remainder, which is $a\bmod b$. You needed the quotient, not the remainder.

Comment: Would a mod b = a - b [a/b] ? 
So for instance. 5 mod 2 = 1
5 mod 2 = 5 - 2[5/2] = 0 ? 
Sorry, I'm just confused.
Oh, I see. 5/2 = 2
^Is there a formula for that? Or do we have to make some sort of assumption. Such as knowing how many times 2 goes into 5.

Comment: $\left\lfloor\frac52\right\rfloor = 2$, so $5\bmod 2 = 5 - 2\left\lfloor\frac52\right\rfloor = 5  -2\cdot2 = 1$, as you said.